# SQL Server - How to import comma delimited file with data that also contains commas

Tags: sql-server, import, delimiter, flat-file

I'm trying to import a comma delimited .txt file into SQL Server. Some of the column's data contains commas as well, but they do not have a text qualifier such as double quotes surrounding them. Here's an example of a row and the first six columns, the fifth of which contains a comma that should not be identified as a delimiter: (After "ELBOW")

```
M,G,ABCA15010845LR      ,a,A150-108 150# 3" ELBOW, FLANGED         ,HC, ...
```

Of course initially, the import wizard splits after ELBOW which is not desired:

[image]

What I've noticed is that this column does have what seems to be tabbed space at the end each time so I was thinking this is how I am meant to identify the end of the text, but when I change that specific column to have the Tab {t} delimiter, it puts all of the rest of the columns under one:

[image]

Is there something that I'm missing or is it simply not possible for me to properly import this data with the format I've been given?

Comment: If you're on SQl Server 2016 SP1+ then `BULK INSERT` supports the `CSV` option for the file's `FORMAT`. You **will**, however, need to ensure that your data is *properly* quote identified; which appears it is not. If you are not using 2016 SP1+ you won't be able to natively do with the T-SQL, as it doesn't support quoted strings. You'll either need to choose a delimiter that doesn't appear in your data, such as a pipe (`|`) or use ETL software such as SSIS that does support identifiers.

Comment: Either way, you need to change your data to either quote the strings that contain commas (`,`) or change the delimiter. As it stands, effectively your CSV is malformed and so no import process could read it reliably, as there's no way to tell where one column end and another begins.

Comment: What tool do you use to import data?

Comment: @Larnu That's what I was thinking, but just wanted to confirm so thanks.

Comment: @МаксимЗолотенко I'm using the SQL Server Management Studio 18.4 Import & Export Wizard

Comment: Maybe your data has a fixed size? I mean: every column can be recognized by a given count of symbols?

Comment: The import & Export Wizard is effectively a dtsx (SSIS) package in the background. @Reddy , so *would* support quote identified values, but you need to first ensure the values *are* quoted. They aren't at the moment, so there is no way to differentiate if a `,` is part of the string or a column delimiter. This means your file *needs* to be fixed, as (like i said) it's malformed. Once you fix the malformed file, you'll find this trivial from SQL Server's side of things.

Comment: If it is fixed width, like @МаксимЗолотенко said, then it would work, but that seems odd. If a file is fixed width, then it wouldn't contain delimiters (as there's no need). If it both fixed width and delimited, you'd need to import the data and then "trim" (not `TRIM`) the commas from the start of the values. (It's far easier in T-SQL to remove a character from the start of a string, than it is from the end).

Comment: Also, if your issue only in 5th and 6th columns, so you can import data as is and then just join these two columns to one. I mean: if all rows in your file have a comma in the same place, so they can be loaded as-is (with parsing one column on two) and then just to be joined.

Comment: It appears that it is fixed-width (well Ragged). I originally dismissed this as well since it is also delimited. @МаксимЗолотенко your suggestion would not work in my case as some values have multiple commas. What I have done is made each comma into its own column just so I don't have to deal with it. I realize that trimming them out would be more proper, but I only require this imported data temporarily to conduct a comparison after which it will be deleted so it does not matter. I've got the import running now, thank you for your help guys! I'll mark as the answer if you leave one.